# Find missing numbers in array in O(log(n)) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, complexity-theory

I'm given two arrays A and B where A is completely filled with positive integers and B is A with some constant number of elements turned into zeroes. I'm also given an arbitrary function that takes an array and gives the sum of the array in O(1) from an a to b where a and b are indices in the array.

I'm supposed to design an algorithm that turns array B into array A in O(log(n)) time, but I'm having difficulties seeing how that is possible.

I've come up with a solution that is O(n) where I simply compare the index of A to the index of B. If they are the same, I continue through the loop and if they are different, I update the value of B[i] to be A[i]. I don't see a way to improve this, especially if the arrays are unsorted.

Comment: Is the summing function you're given supposedly O(1)?

Comment: Yes I'll add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the given function *sum*. As described, you would call it as `sum(array, i, j)` and it would return the sum of `array[i] + ... + array[j-1]`. I assume the range excludes the index at *j* itself, but the reasoning is the same if it would be included.

Let's also call *k* the number of zeroes in *B*.

Now you can use a binary search to find the left-most 0 in *B*, by comparing `sum(A, 0, i)` with `sum(B, 0, i)` while varying *i* according to the binary search method. Then when the lowest index is found for which those sums are not equal, then you know *B[i]* is zero, and in *O(logn)* time.

So then assign the corresponding (non-zero) value from *A[i]* to *B[i]*. Then repeat this *k* times. Since *k* is constant, it does not influence the time complexity: *O(klogn)* is still *O(logn)* when *k* is constant, like for instance 2.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript with an example input, and *k=2*.

```js
// Implementation of the hidden function, which (contrary to this implementation)
// should run in constant time
function sum(arr, i, j) {
    result = 0;
    while (i < j) {
        result += arr[i++];
    }
    return result;
}

// example
let a = [3,2,6,7,1,9,8,5];
let b = [3,2,0,7,1,9,0,5];
let n = a.length;
let k = 2;

for (let times = 0; times < k; times++) {
    // Apply binary search
    let low = 0;
    let high = n;
    while (low < high) {
        let mid = (low + high + 1) >> 1;
        if (sum(a, 0, mid) == sum(b, 0, mid)) {
            low = mid;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    // Found index where zero is at:
    b[low] = a[low];
}

console.log(b);
```

## When *k* is not known

...then it is not constant, but variable. The time complexity then becomes *O((k+1)logn)*, which is *O(klogn)*, and the loop must keep going until a search no longer finds a zero (at the (k+1)<sup>th</sup> iteration):

```js
// Implementation of the hidden function, which (contrary to this implementation)
// should run in constant time
function sum(arr, i, j) {
    result = 0;
    while (i < j) {
        result += arr[i++];
    }
    return result;
}

// example
let a = [3,2,6,7,1,9,8,5];
let b = [3,2,0,7,1,9,0,5];
let n = a.length;
// no definition of k here

while (true) {
    let low = 0;
    let high = n;
    while (low < high) {
        let mid = (low + high + 1) >> 1;
        if (sum(a, 0, mid) == sum(b, 0, mid)) {
            low = mid;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    if (low >= n) break; // no zero found
    // Found index where zero is at:
    b[low] = a[low];
}
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have a question, however. You set k = 2 because you knew that's how many zeroes were in b. What if you didn't know how many zeroes were in b. Wouldn't it take linear time to find out the amount of zeroes?

Comment: Yes, but your question stated that the number of zeroes is constant, so it is known. If you don't know it, then it is variable. In that case it becomes part of the time complexity and the `for` loop must add a check to see if the complete sum of A and B is equal, which is like finding out whether there are still zeroes. But that solution would be *O(klogn)*. I added a section on this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search for a zero'd element. (Hint: if `sum(A, lo, hi) ≠ sum(B, lo, hi)` then the range contains at least one zero'd element. If you have such a range, you can divide it on half: if the first half contains azero'd element continue with the first half, otherwise continue with the second half. Stop when you get to a one-element range.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you briefly explain why this is O(log n)?

Comment: @odenwright: how many times can you divide N in half before it reaches 1?